# Configuring Postfix as SMTP relay (only)

Tags: smtp, postfix

I have a Postfix 2.5.1 on a Debian 4.0 PPC server. I intend to use this as an SMTP relay for outgoing email from my mobile phone (as my phone service provider recently dropped their SMTP server).

The Postfix server is behind a NAT router to which I have added some port-forwarding rules for inbound SMTP. This works OK.

Currently the `main.cf` has a large set of restrictions listed under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` which are not needed and which end with `permit` (which I understand is the default anyway if all rules are inapplicable)

I don't know why the existing `main.cf` doesn't have rules organised under other sections like `smtpd_client_restrictions` etc as the [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html) do. However I feel it's best for me to use the conventions in the main.cf supplied with the software rather than re-organise.

in main.cf can I simplify my restrictions to this?

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
 permit_mynetworks
 permit_sasl_authenticated
 reject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, yes, you can simplify your configuration to the example you've given.

In general, I don't think there would be any problem with setting `smtpd_client_restrictions` in your configuration as well. The default configuration is probably set up with goals different from yours in mind.

Just keep in mind that `smtpd_client_restrictions` apply before the client even had the ability to communicate over SMTP. So there is no SASL authentication data available anyway.

Given that you only want to use the server yourself, from your phone, you

1. don't know which IP address you'll have, so applying a `reject` based on `mynetworks` wouldn't be useful to you.
2. allowing anyone but yourself (being an authenticated user) to send email through the server isn't something you care about.

Comment: Your statement about `smtpd_client_restrictions` applied before AUTH is true when parameter `smtpd_delay_reject` = `no`. In the default configuration however, the value of `smtpd_delay_reject` is `yes`. See [this page](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#timing) for the reason.